# Wildcard copy files in PHP

Tags: php, linux, bash, command-line

I want to perform the equivalent of the following bash (shell) command from within a PHP script:

```
cp --parents -t ../../htdocs/host/$2/ *.html *.js *.png *.ogg *.mp3 Sprites/*.js
```

But when I tried using the PHP system() command, it was not working, presumably because cp is part of the shell and not a stand-alone executable. And I don't think the PHP copy() function supports wildcards, or if it does, it certainly doesn't support the command line switches I'm specifying. What's are the easiest and best ways to perform this within PHP. I could create a shell script and call system() on that, but that seems hokey.

**EDIT:** Comment correct; I believe I had a permission problem. Why did my call to mkdir("blahblah/htdocs/host/$REV", 775) not set permissions to owner and group writable?

Comment: did you check permissions and that you execute this command in the right directory, you are using relative paths there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, as the comment indicated, indeed `cp` is not part of the shell, and I think the error had to do with permissions. I wasn't clear on how to set the directory permissions when I ran the `mkdir` command, so it wasn't owner writable. So unless there's a good reason not to use the `system()` function, I will probably go with my existing solution and just correct my `mkdir` permissions.

My `mkdir` had specified 775 as the mode, but because I neglected to include the "0" prefix (0775) it was interpreted as decimal instead of octal, I think. Correcting that solved everything. One little character makes a really big difference!

Comment: redirect stderr to stdout (append 2>&1 to the end of the command) so you'll see the reason why cp failed). Could be because of permissions or wrong CWD.

Comment: @strkol Thanks for the tip; I already figured that one out, and that's how I was able to answer my question here.

Answer (score 10):

PHP has a `glob()` function that accepts wildcards. It's not as straightforward as a shell line, but you can do something like this:

```
foreach (glob("*.html") as $htmlFile) {
    copy($htmlFile, $targetDir);
}
```

Comment: Will I have to "manually"/explicitly create the "Sprites" sub-directory?

Comment: Yes, mkdir() in PHP has an option to ignore if it already exists. This might save you a few lines.